# IAM Policy for subgroups in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

While creating Users in Cloud. In IAM, Password policy. If you set password policy in inner sub user then it affects to parent user as well.
How is it possible ?
Example . I created user called xyz under root. I will login in xyz and change the password policy. But it affects Root user password policy as well.

Comment: Root=Email address used to create the account. Are you sure that you are referring to this root? As per document, "The IAM password policy does not apply to the AWS root account password." 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_passwords_account-policy.html

Comment: @sudo - good one. I work with IAM everyday and I did not realize that the password policy does not apply to the root user. Then I also don't use the root user unless really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The password policy that you set is for the account, not for a specific user and not for a group of users. It applies to the passwords of all IAM users. It does not apply to the AWS root account password.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod. In that case is it not possible for me to hold the Root account and give limited privileges to users created under Root.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking if you can create IAM users with lesser permissions than the root user (yes, you can)? Are you asking if you can set different password policies on different groups of IAM users within an account (no, you can't)?